# make put request in rspec properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

all!

I wish to know how to make PUT/PATCH request from RSpec to test Rails 5.1.2 API, like that:

```
describe 'PUT /users/:id' do

  context '# check success update' do
    it 'returns status code 204' do
      put 'update',  params: { user: { id: 3, email: 'newmail@ya.ru'} }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
    end
  end
end
```

Got the following error:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users", :user=>{:id=>3, :email=>"newmail@ya.ru"}}
```

Routes are ok:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern          Controller#Action
 users GET    /users(.:format)     users#index
       POST   /users(.:format)     users#create
  user GET    /users/:id(.:format) users#show
       PATCH  /users/:id(.:format) users#update
       PUT    /users/:id(.:format) users#update
       DELETE /users/:id(.:format) users#destroy
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `Rails 5` you'll need to provide `params` options and `id` must be outside of the `user` params:

```
describe 'PUT /users/:id' do
  context '# check success update' do

    before do
      put 'update', params: { id: 3, user: { email: 'newmail@ya.ru'} }
    end

    it 'returns status code 204' do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
    end
  end
end
```